# How to execute type save sql queries with C#? or Looking for SQL wrapping API for C#

Tags: library, c#, api, sql

Instead of executing sql queries with plain query Strings I would like to use some kind of builder pattern to be able to execute type save sql queries in C#.
In other words I am looking for an SQL wrapper API.

For Java there is JOOQ: 
https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.9/manual/getting-started/tutorials/jooq-in-7-steps/

It generates some code from a database (e.g. static classes, enumerations) and that code can then be referenced to create type save queries, e.g.

```
 Result<Record> result = create.select().from(AUTHOR).fetch();

 for (Record r : result) {
      Integer id = r.getValue(AUTHOR.ID);
      String firstName = r.getValue(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME);
      String lastName = r.getValue(AUTHOR.LAST_NAME);

      System.out.println("ID: " + id + " first name: " + firstName + " last name: " + lastName);
 }
```

Is there a similar library for C#?

Comment: In C#, this is usually done using LINQ. Is that acceptable for you?

Comment: If you write this as answer I'll accept it. I am still struggling on how to generate the "LINQ to SQL classes" item for SqLite but that's another topic. The general idea is shown here for a microsoft database: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8K_QKIX0wcc